# Revert killall -KILL Dock

Tags: macos, finder, dock

I'm playing around with Dock and until now I was using `killall Dock` command to relaunch it.

Now I used `killall -KILL Dock` and my Dock went down without relaunching itself. I tried restarting my mac but it did not help.

I tried to open also `/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock/Contents/MacOS/Dock` but all I'm getting is:

```
2018-08-18 22:05:31.276 Dock[1061:44244] -[__NSCFNumber stringByExpandingTildeInPath]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe5cdf6a4f4b8bcfb
2018-08-18 22:05:31.277 Dock[1061:44244] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber stringByExpandingTildeInPath]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe5cdf6a4f4b8bcfb'
```

Is there any way I can get my Dock back :(?

Comment: Check to see if the Dock is hiding, press **⌥⌘D** (Option-Command-D), Also, in Terminal, run `pgrep Dock` and if it doesn't return the `PID`, then run `open -a Dock` and let us know what happens.

Comment: The shortcut does not work at all. `pgrep Dock` returns a PID and `open -a Dock` does nothing too. Also doing `killall Dock` returns `No matching processes belonging to you were found`

Comment: I've just updated my comment above

Comment: Anther update. I did `killall Finder` then `open -a Dock` and now `killall Dock` does not return anything at all - so it seems that it should be working, but it is not :( And after doing nothing at all in terminal and trying to do `killall Dock` again it returns the error :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, fortunately I found where the problem was - it was the `desktoppicture.db` file located in `~/Library/Application Support/Dock/`. Probably a corrupted one. Removing it made the macOS replaced it automagically with a new one :)

Comment: Please accept your answer. This will stop it from coming back to the front page every so often in the future.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I will do it as soon as I can - still one day before I can accept it :)

Comment: Good. I keep forgetting the various time limits around here. 8-)

Comment: Had the same issue... I wasted two hours fighting that...

Comment: This worked for me! I'm just curious how you found out that `desktoppicture.db` was the culprit?

Comment: @DataCrusader I was playing around with this file, learning how it works, along with the Dock-related stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

I would try <kbd>⌥⌘D</kbd> first. If that doesn't work go to [Apple Support Downloads](http://support.apple.com/downloads), then search for, download, and run the combo 10.13.6 update (or the latest combo update available for your system version). That's may be the simplest, fastest way to fix something like this.